# Can Miss Peregrine see the hollowgasts?

Tags: miss-peregrines-home

In the film "Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children", there's a scene
which reveals that Miss Peregrine kills a hollow every "day". We are told
that Jake, and his grandfather Abe, could see the hollowgasts, which is why
the other peculiars need his protection.

Wouldn't Miss Peregrine need to see the hollow in order to shoot it, or did
Abe help her?

Comment: P.S. the scene is one of the changes between film and book.

Answer (score 1):

More of an opinion, given the setup in the film. It looks like it could have been either a "Groundhog Day" effect, repeated attempts over a multitude of times to narrow it down or Abe helped her set it up before he left.

> The outline of the Hollow on the ground and the precise timing of
>  when the shot needed to be taken.

She isn't able to in any case, so I would guess the latter.

Comment: In the movie I assumed that she can't see them. she just knows when and where the hollow will be and shoots it. Olive says to Jacob to not disturb Miss Peregrine as she could miss

Answer (score 1):

In the book, no she can't.

In the film, the scene you refer to is part of a sequence explaining the peculiarities of ymbrynes to the audience and the threat of the hollows.
There are later scenes in which Miss Peregrine does not see them.

We the audience can see hollows in several scenes, so showing them to us as Miss Peregrine follows the time loop to the second is a cinematic ploy.  It is a consequence of trying to fit a book into a two-hour film and stay coherent.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have not read the books but, if she were able to have seen it, she wouldn't need to wait for it to be at a mark or certain point (Unless it being where she knows it's head would be).  It could of course have been with Abes help but going off without his help..

---

In the movie she has outlined where the Hollow's corpse will be each time, if you pay attention to the scene she watches the grass and stays silent in order to hear it. Emma has to tell Jake to keep it down in order not to throw her off, him speaking or making a noise would've definitely ruined her set up. 
She could've misheard or the Hollow could've simply gone over to them instead, thus creating a bit of a bigger issue.
Looking back at the grass, it not only makes noise but it is tall grass and a patch of it in a specific area. That area being where she found out where the Hollow had come from. It also happened to have come from the ocean, meaning there'd be water there as well to help indicate it's position. I  cannot say how she would've known where it's head would be and not to have assumed it'd slouch but that's my view of it.